# Tiny table problem

Tags: tables, fontsize

I'm trying to make a table like this:
[image]

But when i use this code to generate it:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \caption{Elastic properties of tissue}
 \label{jj}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\huge
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\hline
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{decagonal prism-shaped tumor}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{10-winged star-shaped base tumor}\\
 \hline
Number of elements & Element type&Maximum relative error(\%) &Computational time(sec)&Number of elements & Element type&Maximum relative error(\%)&Computational time(sec)\\
\hline
21796 & C3D4T &0&19.27&22362&C3D4T&0&21.49\\
\hline
29725 & C3D4T &0.0751&23.44&29869&C3D4T&0.0665&23.56\\
\hline
44029 & C3D4T &0.0382&29.82&43366&C3D4T&00269&30.81\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

I get this:
[image]

Which the inside text is so tiny.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

In comparison to your code snipped I make the following changes:

- made complete MWE
- use `tabularx` instead `tabular`
- renewcommand for column type `X`
- use `booktabs` for horizontal rules
- reduce font size to `\small`

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \small
\caption{Elastic properties of tissue}
    \label{jj}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{8}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{decagonal prism-shaped tumor}
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{10-winged star-shaped base tumor}            \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8}
Number of elements  & Element type  & Maximum relative error (\%)   & Computa\-tional time (sec) 
    & Number of elements    & Element type  & Maximum relative error (\%)   & Computa\-tional time (sec)    \\
    \midrule
21796   &   C3D4T   &   0       &   19.27   &   22362   &   C3D4T   &   0       &   21.49       \\
29725   &   C3D4T   &   0.0751  &   23.44   &   29869   &   C3D4T   &   0.0665  &   23.56       \\
44029   & C3D4T     &   0.0382  &   29.82   &   43366   &   C3D4T   &   00269   &   30.81       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it makes a frame for the whole of page!

Comment: yes, because I use it as option in `geometry` package to show page layout. it serves only for test purposed, for document production it had to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a start, by stacking the column headers in a `\Centerstack`.

EDITED to add a column and use `\cline` to produce line-break effect.  Additionally, set in `\sffamily`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{/}
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\sffamily
\centering
 \caption{Elastic properties of tissue}
 \label{jj}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\huge
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\hline
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{decagonal prism-shaped tumor}&& \multicolumn{4}{c}{10-winged star-shaped base tumor}\\
\cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}
\Centerstack{Number of/ elements} & \Centerstack{Element/type}&
\Centerstack{Maximum/ relative/ error(\%)} &\Centerstack{Computational /time(sec)}&&
\Centerstack{Number/ of/ elements} & \Centerstack{Element/ type}&
\Centerstack{Maximum/ relative/ error(\%)}&\Centerstack{Computational/ time(sec)}\\
\cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}
21796 & C3D4T &0&19.27&&22362&C3D4T&0&21.49\\
\cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}
29725 & C3D4T &0.0751&23.44&&29869&C3D4T&0.0665&23.56\\
\cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}
44029 & C3D4T &0.0382&29.82&&43366&C3D4T&00269&30.81\\
\cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you want to resize you table by adapting the width and height of the produced table with an `adjustbox`, as if it was a picture you wanted to resize. It is not the better way to do it. Indeed, you see that the font size is also shrunk.

There are plenty of ways to define a table according to its maximal dimensions. Here is a suggestion using [`tabulary`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary). It uses following syntax:

```
\begin{tabulary}{<maximal_width_of_the_table>}{<column_types>}
    <your_table>
\end{tabulary}
```

`tabulary` introduces new column types: `L`, `C`, `R`, and `J` that have adjustable width (see documentation).

You can observe that, instead of writing `CCCCCCCC` as coulmn types, you can use the trick : `*{8}{C}` (i.e. 8 times the column `C`).
Last advice: when you create tables, always load the `array` package!

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{array, tabulary}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{Elastic properties of tissue}
        \label{jj}
            \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{8}{C}}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{4}{c}{decagonal prism-shaped tumor}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{10-winged star-shaped base tumor}\\
                \hline
                Number of elements & Element type&Maximum relative error(\%) &Computational time(sec)&Number of elements & Element type&Maximum relative error(\%)&Computational time(sec)\\
                \hline
                21796 & C3D4T &0&19.27&22362&C3D4T&0&21.49\\
                \hline
                29725 & C3D4T &0.0751&23.44&29869&C3D4T&0.0665&23.56\\
                \hline
                44029 & C3D4T &0.0382&29.82&43366&C3D4T&00269&30.81\\
                \hline
            \end{tabulary}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: See also [Steven's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319082/64454) for refinement using `\cline`s and `\Centerstack`!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `adjustbox`! You can have a table in `\footnotesize` loading `geometry`, which gives by default more sensible margins, playing with the value of `\tabcolsep` and using a mix of `tabularx` and `makecell` in order to have multiline column heads. Here are two possibilities, both replacing  `\hline` with the rules of `booktabs`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry} \usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
    \usepackage{array, graphicx, caption, booktabs, adjustbox, makecell, tabularx}%

    \usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
   \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}\setlength\cmidrulewidth{\lightrulewidth}
  \captionsetup{font=small}
  \caption{Elastic properties of tissue}
  \label{jj}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{2}{cXX}X}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{decagonal prism-shaped tumor}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{10-winged star-shaped base tumor}\\
    \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r){1-4} \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r){5-8}
    \thead{Number of & & & & & & & \\ elements} & \thead{Element\\ type} & Maximum \makebox[\linewidth]{relative error (\%)} & Computational time (sec)& \thead{Number of \\ elements} & \thead{Element \\type} & Maximum \makebox[\linewidth]{relative error (\%)} & Computational time (sec) \\
    \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r){1-4} \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r){5-8}
    21796 & C3D4T & 0 & 19.27 & 22362 & C3D4T & 0 & 21.49 \\
    \addlinespace
    29725 & C3D4T & 0.0751 & 23.44 & 29869 & C3D4T & 0.0665 & 23.56 \\
    \addlinespace
    44029 & C3D4T & 0.0382 & 29.82 & 43366 & C3D4T & 00269 & 30.81 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}\setlength\cmidrulewidth{\lightrulewidth}
  \captionsetup{font=small}
  \caption{Elastic properties of tissue}
  \label{jj}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{2}{cXX}X}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{decagonal prism-shaped tumor}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{10-winged star-shaped base tumor}\\
    \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r){1-4} \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r){5-8}
    \thead{Number of & & & & & & & \\ elements} & \thead{Element\\ type} & Maximum \makebox[\linewidth]{relative error (\%)} & Computational time (sec)& \thead{Number of \\ elements} & \thead{Element \\type} & Maximum \makebox[\linewidth]{relative error (\%)} & Computational time (sec) \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(l){5-8}
    \addlinespace[-\belowrulesep]
    \rowcolor{lightgray!30}21796 & C3D4T & 0 & 19.27 & 22362 & C3D4T & 0 & 21.49 \\[1.5ex]
    29725 & C3D4T & 0.0751 & 23.44 & 29869 & C3D4T & 0.0665 & 23.56 \\[1.5ex]
    \rowcolor{lightgray!30}44029 & C3D4T & 0.0382 & 29.82 & 43366 & C3D4T & 00269 & 30.81 \\[1.5ex]
    \addlinespace[-\aboverulesep]
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Ìmprovement added:**

Here is a solution with a `small` fontsize. I used `caption` for caption formatting and a correct vertical spacing between above caption and table. The use of `X` column type is different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, booktabs, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\sffamily\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\captionsetup{font={sf, small},labelfont=bf, labelsep=period}
 \caption{Elastic properties of tissue}
 \label{jj}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{ccc >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{decagonal prism-shaped tumor}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{10-winged star-shaped base tumor}\\
 \cmidrule(lr){1-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-8}
\makecell{Number of\\ elements} & \makecell{Element\\ type} & \makecell{Maximum\\ relative\\ error(\%)} & \makecell{Computational\\ time (sec)} & \makecell{Number of\\ elements} & \makecell{Element\\ type} & \makecell{Maximum\\ relative\\ error (\%)} & \makecell{Computational\\ time (sec)} \\
\midrule
21796 & C3D4T &0&19.27&22362&C3D4T&0&21.49\\
\addlinespace
29725 & C3D4T &0.0751&23.44&29869&C3D4T&0.0665&23.56\\
\addlinespace
44029 & C3D4T &0.0382&29.82&43366&C3D4T&00269&30.81\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]