# How to fit a large column to page without rendering the text too small?

Tags: tables, tabularx, article, adjustbox

I'm trying to fit a large column in a two column article document, such that it spans the width of the columns. The first solution I tried to have the table fit the page was to use the `\adjustbox` package with the option `{max width=\linewidth}`. However the text became almost unreadable.

The second solution I tried was from this [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319087/214185). As such, I made the necessary adjustments to change from the `\tabular` to the `tabularx` environment. Nevertheless, as its possible to observe from the image below, the text is getting to condensed and the stacking is at some times excessive (specially in the first column).

Is there any way to improve the aspect of this table ?

Thank you for your time.

My code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newgeometry{vmargin={30mm}, hmargin={20mm,20mm}, columnsep={10mm}}   % set the margins
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}




\begin{document}



\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{table*}[]
\scriptsize
\centering
%\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{11}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Extracellular amplitude} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{"In-cell" amplitude} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
 &
  \# of electrodes &
  Cell type &
  Poration method &
  "In-cell" access &
  AP ($\mu$V) &
  Sub-threshould ($\mu$V) &
  AP (mV) &
  Sub-threshould (mV) &
  "In-cell" recording duration &
  Ref. \\ \midrule
 Nanopatterned Volcano-shaped MEA (NVMEA) &
  32 &
  Rat ventricular cardiomyocites &
  — &
  yes &
  — &
  — &
  1.5-20.3 &
  — &
  3-66 min &
  \cite{desbiolles_intracellular_2019-1} \\
  Commercially available MEAs &
  60 / 64 &
  HiPSC-CMs &
  Plasmonic optoacoustic &
  yes / yes &
  \textgreater 100 / $\sim$3000 &
  — &
  5-10 / 9-10 &
  — &
  $\sim$ 20 min &
  \cite{melle_intracellular_2020} \\
Vertical Nanowire MEA (VNMEA) &
  25\tnote{*} &
  HEK293T &
  Optostimulation &
  yes &
  2000-3000 &
  — &
  50-80 &
  — &
  24 h &
  \cite{yoo_long-term_2020} \\
Hydrophobe / Hydrophylic MEA &
  5 &
  Mouse sciatic nerve axons &
  — &
  no &
  40-150 &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  \cite{guo_extracellular_2020} \\
  U-NWFET &
  — &
  DRG neurons / HiPSC-CMs &
  — &
  yes / yes &
  — &
  — &
  60-100 / $\sim$50 &
  3-5 / — &
  10-150 s / 100-900 s &
  \cite{zhao_scalable_2019} \\
  VNMEA &
  64\tnote{*} &
  Rat primary cultured neurons &
  electrical stimulation &
  yes &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  \cite{kwon_nanoelectrode-mediated_2020} \\
  (PtB) Vertical Nanoelectrode CMOS &
  4096 &
  Rat primary cultured neurons &
  continued current injection &
  yes &
  50-300 &
  — &
  0.2-10 &
  $\sim$ 0.45 &
  $\sim$ 8-19 min &
  \cite{abbott_nanoelectrode_2020} \\ \bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*] Each pad has various vertical Si-NWs
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
%\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Do not forget to put a caption!}
\label{tab:advancements}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit:
I took the advice of David Carlisle and created acronyms (which I then placed a footnote with their meaning), together with the code provided by leandriis. The final result is here:
[image]

Comment: never scale tables with resizebio/adjustbox etc, it makes inconsistent font sizes as you see. Reformatting the table to fit really needs subject knowledge so hard to help, eg the sub-threshould  (spelling?) column is wide because of the title but has no content at all, can you drop it?

Comment: also `*{11}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}`  is completely the wrong preamble, that says that all the columns should have equal width and allow line breaking which makes no sense here. Just use X for columns 1,3,4 and use `c` for the others

Comment: Can't you really use the whole `\textwidth` just for this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newgeometry{vmargin={30mm}, hmargin={20mm,20mm}, columnsep={10mm}}   % set the margins
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}



\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{table*}[]
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{LcLLccccccc}
\toprule
 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Extracellular amplitude}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{"In-cell" amplitude}}  \\ \cmidrule(r){6-7}\cmidrule(r){8-9}
 &
  \thead{\# of\\ elec-\\trodes} &
  \thead{Cell\\ type} &
  \thead{Poration\\ method} &
  \thead{"In-cell"\\ access}&
  \thead{AP\\ ($\mu$V)} &
  \thead{Sub-\\threshould\\ ($\mu$V)} &
  \thead{AP\\ (mV)} &
  \thead{Sub-\\threshould\\ (mV)} &
  \thead{"In-cell"\\ recording\\ duration} &
  \thead{Ref.} \\ \midrule
 Nanopatterned Volcano-shaped MEA (NVMEA) &
  32 &
  Rat ventricular cardiomyocites &
  — &
  yes &
  — &
  — &
  1.5-20.3 &
  — &
  3-66 min &
  \cite{desbiolles_intracellular_2019-1} \\
  Commercially available MEAs &
  60 / 64 &
  HiPSC-CMs &
  Plasmonic optoacoustic &
  \makecell{yes /\\ yes} &
  \makecell{\textgreater 100 /\\ $\sim$3000} &
  — &
  \makecell{5-10 /\\ 9-10} &
  — &
  $\sim$ 20 min &
  \cite{melle_intracellular_2020} \\
Vertical Nanowire MEA (VNMEA) &
  25\tnote{*} &
  HEK293T &
  Optostimulation &
  yes &
  2000-3000 &
  — &
  50-80 &
  — &
  24 h &
  \cite{yoo_long-term_2020} \\
Hydrophobe / Hydrophylic MEA &
  5 &
  Mouse sciatic nerve axons &
  — &
  no &
  40-150 &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  \cite{guo_extracellular_2020} \\
  U-NWFET &
  — &
  DRG neurons / HiPSC-CMs &
  — &
  \makecell{yes /\\ yes} &
  — &
  — &
  \makecell{60-100 /\\ $\sim$50} &
  3-5 / — &
  \makecell{10-150 s /\\ 100-900 s} &
  \cite{zhao_scalable_2019} \\
  VNMEA &
  64\tnote{*} &
  Rat primary cultured neurons &
  electrical stimulation &
  yes &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  — &
  \cite{kwon_nanoelectrode-mediated_2020} \\
  (PtB) Vertical Nanoelectrode CMOS &
  4096 &
  Rat primary cultured neurons &
  continued current injection &
  yes &
  50-300 &
  — &
  0.2-10 &
  $\sim$ 0.45 &
  $\sim$ 8-19 min &
  \cite{abbott_nanoelectrode_2020} \\ \bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*] Each pad has various vertical Si-NWs
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
%\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Do not forget to put a caption!}
\label{tab:advancements}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```